# Twitter exercise with MongoDB and lack of transactions?

Tags: mongodb, twitter

I was trying to figure out if MongoDB needs transactions and why you wouldn't have everything in a single document. I also know twitter uses HBase which does have transactions so I thought about a tweet and watchers.

If i post a tweet it will be inserted with no problem. But how would I or anyone else find my tweet? I heard mongodb has indexes so maybe I can index author and find my tweet however I can't imagine that being efficient if everyone does that. Also time has to be indexed.

So from what I understand (I think i saw some slides twitter released) twitter has a 'timeline' so everytime a person tweets twitter inserts the tweetid in everyone timeline which is indexed by date and when a given user browse it grabs available tweets sorted by time.

How would that be done in mongodb? The only solution I can think of is having a column in the tweet document saying {SendOut:DateStamp} which is removed when completed. If it didnt complete on the first attempt (checking timestamp to guess if it should be completed by now or not) then I would need to check all the watchers to see who hasn't received it and insert if they didn't. But also since theres no transactions i guess i need to index the SendOut column? Would this solution work? How would I efficiently insert a tweet and give it to everyone watching the user? (if this solution would not work)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing a model similar to pub/sub. Couldn't you instead just track that last post (by date) with each user object that the user last read? Users would requests tweets the same way, using various indexes including time.

I'm not sure what you need transactions for, but Mongo does support atomic operations.

*[Updated]*

So in other words, each user's object stores the dateTime of the last tweet read/delivered. Obviously you would also need the list of subscribed author IDs. To fetch new tweets you would  ask for tweets indexed by both author_id,time properties and then sort by time.

By using the last read date from the user object and using it as the secondary index into your tweets collection, I don't believe you need either pub/sub or transactions to do it.

I might be missing something though.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Couldn't you instead just track that last post (by date) with each user object that the user last read?" I dont think time is a good index as theres are thousands of tweets per minute, most you dont care about. If your watching 100people (thats a low number) and posts are indexed by their author it sounds like it may take a lot of work for 1k users on that server that second searching 100 of their friends with additional work on timestamps. I think a timeline or delivery list would be the only sane solution but i cant think how to implement except mention in my Q

Comment: I've expanded on the post - does that make sense?